# Custom File opener App in android

Tags: android

Dear Folks,
              I am trying to build a custom file opener app for android. What i want is when I click a specific file it should ask me to open with my custom file opener. I have till now assumed that I need to register for a brodcast reciever in my Custom File Opener app so that When any file is selected it would send a broadcast to my Custom File Opener App and it would open the desired file ! Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible.You also need to specify the action and data attributes in intent filter please see links. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html

Comment: Thanks Ashwin, Wil go through the link and check if I can achieve this!